# How do you write an image at a url to your filesystem in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3, filesystems

If there is an image at a public url, how would I write and save it to my local filesystem using Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require "open-uri"

open("http://www.whatever.com/x.png") do |hnd|
  File.open("x.png","wb") {|file| file.puts hnd.read }
end
```

EDIT:

This allows you to use open to load a website, and treat it as normal file handle:

`require "open-uri"`

This loads your image, and passes a handle to the page body, as the parameter `hnd`:

```
open("http://www.whatever.com/x.png") do |hnd|
```

This opens a file in binary mode ( needed on Windows systems ), and writes the page's content into it:

```
File.open("x.png","wb") {|file| file.puts hnd.read }
```

The content is obtained via the read method, which tries to read it completely before writing it.

Comment: what does the saving? `read`? can you explain where you specify the path? why do you `puts` the file?

Comment: @Justin: He isn't using `Kernel.puts`, but `File#puts` which will write to a file. Note that that particular call is in a block being passed to `File.open` and `file` is a block-local variable.

Comment: @coreyward I'd still like a more in-depth explanation of exactly what is going on in this code, such as what each method is doing.

Comment: @Justin Meltzer, everything is very standard, very basic Ruby. No further explanations should be necessary.

Comment: @Senthess and I can just specify the entire path where `x.png` is?

Comment: @Justin Meltzer, you can write wherever you want, sure. You can specify a relative path, absolute one. It will work either way.